# What are some good companies that offer Canadian tours in the Rockies or the Maritimes?

Tags: canada, tours, national-parks, banff

There are a lot of good companies out there which offer group tours in South America, Asia and Africa.  I am looking for something similar but for Canada.  The itinerary I am looking for is something like that for the Rockies:

- Day 1: Arrive in Calgary
- Day 2: Bus ride to Rocky Mountain
- A few days in Banff visiting the various locations by bus
- Day n: Drive back to Calgary

I am looking for something affordable, maybe 3 star hotels, guest houses and some camping.  The tour price will include the hotels, local transport between the cities and a guide for the duration of the tour.  Does such a group tour exist in Canada?  I've been to similar tours abroad and I want to do a few of those in Canada, mainly in the Rockies and the Maritimes.

I don't feel comfortable driving which is the main reason I like those kind of group tours. Any advice on a list of potential companies that offer that kind of package?

**EDIT**

I am not looking for a tour which does both Rockies and Maritimes in one go.  I plan to do them separately in different years.

Comment: you understand that the Maritimes are over 2000 miles from the Rockies?

Comment: I know, I don't plan to do both tours in one go.  Maybe do the Rockies in one year and the Maritimes the next.

Comment: I recommend you edit out the Maritimes part from this question, and ask a separate question for the Maritimes or the Atlantic provinces.

Answer (score 2):

The official website of Alberta Tourism is [`travelalberta.com`](http://travelalberta.com/) or `1 800 ALBERTA` if you can dial North American toll free numbers (eg with Skype.) They will be happy to send you travel guides with all kinds of listings of various places you could go and firms that will take you. They have a search function on their website which I learned to despise in mere minutes. [Banff has its own page there](http://travelalberta.com/Places%20to%20Go/Parks/Banff%20National%20Park.aspx) but there's no mention of tours from Calgary.

Don't let that discourage you though; they definitely exist. I've been there and I've been behind the buses. Be sure to look into Jasper, Lake Louise etc when checking all this out. It's only an hour or so from Calgary to Banff; once when I had business in Calgary we went to Banff for lunch. So you should be able to fit in multiple locations on a day trip. I've also spent multiple days there seeing something different every day: there's lots of flexibility.